# Prove there is a unique solution for $\log x=cx$ when $c \le 0$

Tags: calculus, inequality

When $c=0$ it is clear, because $\log x=0 \iff x=e$. 
But when $c<0$, given $x$ has to be bigger than $0$ (otherwise $\log x$ is not defined), $0<x<1$ and then both $\log x$ and $cx$ are negative. How can I show there is one solution?? 
In other sub-questions I defined $f(x)=\log(x)-cx$ and checked extremum, but the extremum was $c$ dependent and in that case its $x$ coordinate was below $0$, for which $\log(x)$ wasn't defined.

Comment: check the extrema of $\frac{\log x}{x}$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uniqueness use the fact that $\log x$ is increasing and $cx$ is decreasing.

For existence you can use e.g. the intermediate value theorem: $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \log x - cx = -\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} \log x - cx = \infty$.